# Docker daemon won't start out of space catch-22

Tags: docker

So far every question/answer I've seen for cleaning up a docker install uses the docker daemon, but we seem to have encountered a catch-22: the docker daemon won't start if the drive is out of space, but you cannot delete containers/images unless the docker daemon is running:

You can't start the docker daemon:

```
~$ systemctl status docker.service
Jun 07 13:58:52 server-name docker[24266]: time=snip level=fatal msg=
"Error starting daemon: write /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db: no space left on device"
```

So, anyone know how to get around this Catch-22?

I can't delete a container via the normal method because that requires the docker daemon to be running.

I can't run the docker daemon because the drive was filled by said container.

I can't increase the storage because this is a physical hard drive which is at capacity: `/dev/mapper/drive-name  932G  926G   64K 100% /var/lib/docker`

Any way to delete a container/image without the docker daemon running, or run the daemon on a drive that's out of space? There are other containers I'm hoping to salvage. I do know the hash for the container I want to remove.

Comment: The files are in `/var/lib/docker`. If you have volume ids, you can remove them manually there. Same goes for layers. I think I've done that before, but there is no guarantee Docker won't complain when starting back up.

Comment: @kichik any chance you can be more specific? I've got two volumes, both of which I'd like to keep in `volumes`. `containers` appears to carry metadata, rather than actual data. `btrfs` contains `subvolumes` which presumably relate to the containers but none match the container hash I've got.

Comment: Try looking for commin image hashes on a different machines. Then look for that hash in `brtfs` or `overlay2` and delete it. Or maybe just nuke all the images? You probably just want the volumes anyway, right? Maybe check on a different computer first that it doesn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to address a **Thin Pool Minimum Free Space** error. You may have twisted your system enough to be in the second error state:

> devmapper: Thin Pool has **X** free data blocks which is less than minimum required **Y** free data blocks.

> Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devmapper: Failed to find uuid for device /dev/mapper/docker

**Environment level-set:**

- You have an ecosystem that appeared stable for months.
- You're not spinning up new images or significantly changing things.
- Your containers have now/recently exited/died/crashed.
- Attempting to restart them fails.
- You start chasing disk space related issues and you probably ran this (or some variant):
- `docker system prune -a -f --volumes`

This doesn't change the end error you get. Perhaps the images start to build, but then still crash due to a space available issue. Now you don't have the pre-built images, so the memory needed actually increased.

A lot of the guides tell you to just move away from the thin pool driver or completely reinstall docker, but the anticipation is that you're looking for a quick fix and you probably have something environmental prohibiting that.

This is what I did, which finally worked, without a full reinstall.

1.) Stop Docker

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

2.) Delete the data, devicemapper, and tmp-old directories

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/data
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/tmp-old
```

3.) Restart the docker agent. It will rebuild the devicemapper folded and stubs.

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

4.) Rebuild and relaunch your containers as normal.

```
docker run ...
```